# how to execute .vbs script using putty

Tags: putty

I have various .vbs script that executes smoothly using SecureCRT but I would like to execute them using putty.

Comment: Show us how exactly are you executing the command.

Comment: I input the following to the putty command prompt.                                             > putty.exe ... -m "c:\users\nuvali\script.vbs"

Comment: You cannot execute vbs this way. What does your vbs do? How do you execute it in SecureCRT

Comment: On the secureCRT, from the menu, I select Script, then Run and select the .vbs script. The script will run various show commands and will save all the logs in a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like SecureCRT can run vba scripts directly somehow (it probably has some API for that).  PuTTY cannot do that.